# Is it possible to have a combined transform mixin in sass?

Tags: css, sass, transform, mixins

I want to recreate the following with scss:

```
transform: rotate(-20deg) scale(1) skew(-20deg)  translate(-40px);
```

But I want to avoid typing multiple browser prefixes so I have:

```
@mixin transform($transforms) {
   -moz-transform: $transforms;
     -o-transform: $transforms;
    -ms-transform: $transforms;
-webkit-transform: $transforms;
      transform: $transforms;
```

}

Which works fine with individual transforms such as:

```
 @mixin scale($scale) {
 @include transform(scale($scale));
```

}

I have tried to include the functions

```
 @mixin skewTitle($rot, $sca, $ske, $tran){
  @include transform(scale($sca));
  @include transform(skew(#{$ske}deg));
  @include transform(translate($tran));
  @include transform(rot(#{$rot}deg));
}
```

But it only combines them in succession which causes one to override the other.

```
-moz-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: translate(-40px);
  -o-transform: translate(-40px);
  -ms-transform: translate(-40px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-40px);
  transform: translate(-40px);
```

I tried combining it all in something like:

```
@include transform: rotate(#{$val}deg) scale($val) skew(#{$val}deg)  translate($val);
```

I tried this but it did not work. Is it possible to combine maps to get something along these lines?

Comment: Why not write it like `@include transform(rotate(#{$rot}deg) scale(#{$sca}) skew(#{$ske}deg)  translate(#{$tran}px));`? It works for me @ sassmeister.com

Comment: Can you show an example? it is not working for me. `@mixin skewTitle($rot, $sca, $ske, $tran){

  @include transform(rotate(#{$rot}deg) scale(#{$sca}) skew(#{$ske}deg) translate(#{$tran}px));

}`

Comment: Please check [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOdKzO). Click the "View Compiled" button to see the compiled CSS.

Comment: Hey, it was a "commas" situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@include transform(rotate(-20deg) scale(1) skew(-20deg) translate(-40px));
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.